# How to make random email generator?

Tags: python

i want to make it so i get 7 random letters form my list and make it into a random email, however i can't get it to print out a full email only 1 letter at a time.

```
import random

letters = ["a", "b","c", "d","e", "f","g", "h","i", "j","k", "l","m", "n",
           "o", "p","q", "r","s", "t","u", "v","w", "x","y", "z",]

random1 = random.choice(letters)

for x in random1(7):
    print (x+"@gmail.com")
```

this only gives me an error and if i fix it, it will only give me one letter emails. The fix is:

```
random1 = random.choice(letters)
print (random1+"@gmail.com")
```

Comment: Please be more specific and detailed. What errors? What does fixing it mean? This seems like a trivial problem, I recommend reading the following article: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Answer (score 16):

Try the following:

```
import random
import string

def random_char(char_num):
       return ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_letters) for _ in range(char_num))

print (random_char(7)+"@gmail.com")
```

you can use `string.ascii_lowercase` if you only want lower case letters

Comment: you don’t need the variable x here you can simply use “_” since nothing is consuming/using x

Answer (score 3):

If you need you can use [faker](https://faker.readthedocs.io/en/master/) library to generate this

```py
import faker
f = faker.Faker()

get_list_of_email(n)
    return [f.email() for _ in range(n)]

# or just print
for i in range(10):
    print(f.email())
```

This could give more real world testing data

Answer (score 2):

```
import secrets
def email_generator():
    return f"{secrets.token_hex(8)}@gmail.com"
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 1):

you could do it this way..though there's probably a more efficient way:

```
import itertools
import random
letters = = ["a", "b","c", "d","e", "f","g", "h","i", "j","k", "l","m", "n",
           "o", "p","q", "r","s", "t","u", "v","w", "x","y", "z",]

all_combos = list(itertools.combinations(letters,7)) #make all 7 letter combinations
all_combos = [''.join(combo) for combo in all_combos] #make them strings
email = random.sample(all_combos,1)[0]+'@gmail.com' #grab a random one, add @gmail.com
```

following your initial approach:

```
email = ''
for _ in range(7):
    letter = random.sample(letters,1)[0]
    email += letter

email += '@gmail.com'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Make sure the "return" is out of for loop, else it'll return only one letter

```
def random_email(char_num):
   random_email = ''
   for x in range(char_num):
       random_email+=''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase))
   return random_email


print(random_email(7) + "@gmail.com")
```